# What happens if i kept open the other output terminals of a 3Tap transformer?

Tags: transformer

I'm having a transformer having 3 pairs of output wires.Out of these 3 pairs I connect my circuit with the first pair of wires and left open all other wires except input.Will it work correctly or leads to any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work just fine, but the copper for the unused secondary windings is a waste in space (you could use a smaller transformer core), in weight (it would be lighter without) and in material, so you will likely not find any commercial product using transformers without using all of its secondary windings.

Answer (score 1):

Because the unused secondaries won't be loaded, there'll be no \$ I^2R\$ losses there and the primary will draw less current than if they were loaded, so the primary's \$ I^2R\$ losses will also be smaller, causing the transformer to run  cooler.

Also, the eddy current losses in the core will be less, causing the transformer to run even cooler; all Good Things.

Answer (score 0):

The only potential problem is if the unused wire ends were to short together or touch something else conductive, so be sure to place some type of insulator over the unused wire ends.